# Popover click event does not work

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

```
$('.pop').each(function () {
    var $elem = $(this);
    $elem.popover({
        placement: 'auto',
        trigger: 'hover',
        html: true,
        container: $elem,
        animation: true,
        content: function () {
            var pop_dest = $(this).attr("data-pop");
            //console.log(plant);
            return $("#"+pop_dest).html();
        }
    });
});

$('#english').click(function() { // ---> THIS PART DOES NOT WORK
    alert("english");
});

$('#turkce').click(function() { // ---> THIS PART DOES NOT WORK
    console.log("turkce");
});
```

I have 2 button in popover. But their click event does not work. How can I fire click event from button click ? My html code is below.

```
<li>
    <a href="javascript: void(0);" id="languages" class="pop" data-html="true" data-toggle="popover" data-pop="popper-content" class="popper">
        <?=$language["languages"]?>
    </a>
    <div class="hide" id="popper-content">
        <ul class="lang-list">
            <li class="en">
                <button id="english">English</button>
            </li>
            <li class="tr">
                <button id="turkce">Türkçe</button>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</li>
```

Comment: what event do you want to trigger?

Comment: $('#english').click(function() {
    alert("english");
}); this part does not work.

Comment: can you try putting the $.each function to see if it works?

Comment: **PLEASE NOTE:** The OP has been suspended for 12 months, so I doubt they'll be back to accept an answer. By all means, keep adding answers/comments for others to learn from, but don't expect your answer to be accepted by the OP.

Answer (score 5):

When you call the `click` function, the buttons are not added to to page yet (since they are in a dynamically added popover) so you have to use something that takes care of future added content:

```
$('body').on('click', '#english', function () {
    alert("english");
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You should delegate the event to make sure the event get's to the desired DOM element if it's not present at the time the js gets executed:

```
$("body").on('click', '#english', function() {
    alert("english");
});

$("body").on('click', '#turkce', function() {
    alert("turkce");
});
```

You can delegate events with jquery by using the `on` method, where the selector is the parent node that will delegate the event to the children, the firs parameter is the event name `click`, the second is the child you want the event to be delegated to `#english` and the third parameter is the handler.

Answer (score 1):

The content of the `popover` is dynamically appended to the page. This means that when you attempt to attach the event handlers when the page loads neither of the buttons exist in the DOM. To fix the problem use a delegated event handler:

```
$(document).on('click', '#english', function() {
    alert("english");
}).on('click', '#turkce', function() { 
    console.log("turkce");
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that `<button>` has a default type of `submit`.  You don't want that default behavior since you provided your own click handler.  You need buttons of [`type="button"`](http://www.w3.org/TR/html51/semantics.html#attr-button-type).

```
<button id="english" type="button">English</button>
```